# Why does IOrganizationService.Update() return "The specified record type does not exist in Microsoft Dynamics CRM."?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

A call to update a record in an early-bound custom entity, the record already retrieved, returns the above message.  Code fragment follows (heavily instrumented but I'll leave everything in as I'm new to CRM code and might remove someting relevant)

```
// retrieve and update ContactFact record -

string strcontactFactId = reader["contactFactId"] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : (string)reader["contactFactId"];
string strcontactId = reader["contactId"] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : (string)reader["contactId"];
whereAmI = "retrieved strcontactId = " + strcontactId;
string straccountId = reader["accountId"] == DBNull.Value ? string.Empty : (string)reader["accountId"];

Guid contactFactId;
Guid contactId;
Guid accountId;
Guid.TryParse(strcontactFactId, out contactFactId);
whereAmI = "try to generate contactId from " + strcontactId;
Guid.TryParse(strcontactId, out contactId);
whereAmI = "generated contactId = " + contactId.ToString();
Guid.TryParse(straccountId, out accountId);

int score = reader.GetInt32(3);

whereAmI = "try to retrieve contactFact " + contactFactId.ToString();
sbtls_contactfact contactFact = (sbtls_contactfact)service.Retrieve("sbtls_contactfact", contactFactId, columnSet);  // xx prob don't need to retrieve current values
whereAmI = "try to set sbtls_ContactId to " + contactId.ToString();
contactFact.sbtls_ContactId = contactId == Guid.Empty ? null : new EntityReference("Contact", contactId);
whereAmI = "successfully set sbtls_ContactId to " + contactId.ToString();
contactFact.sbtls_AccountId = accountId == Guid.Empty ? null : new EntityReference("Account", accountId);
contactFact.sbtls_Score = score;
contactFact.sbtls_Fact = "Updated with contactId " + strcontactId + " parsed to GUID " + contactId.ToString();
whereAmI = "about to update";
service.Update(contactFact);
whereAmI = "updated";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change these two line:

`contactFact.sbtls_ContactId = contactId == Guid.Empty ? null : new EntityReference("Contact", contactId);`

contactFact.sbtls_AccountId = accountId == Guid.Empty ? null : new EntityReference("Account", accountId);

To use lowercase for the `EntityReference.LogicalName` values, so it reads like:

`contactFact.sbtls_ContactId = contactId == Guid.Empty ? null : new EntityReference("contact", contactId);`

contactFact.sbtls_AccountId = accountId == Guid.Empty ? null : new EntityReference("account", accountId);

The logical name is case sensitive and should be lower-case.

Comment: Precisely so, thank you.  Works a treat now.  Sorry for the poor quality of the question; I was a bit rushed at the time I posted it but actually I had done a fair amount of research and experimentation; it just wasn't very well directed as it turned out.

Comment: Glad it worked. Btw, if you use the early bound entities (i.e., `contactFact`) you can get that logical name by using `contactFact.EntityLogicalName` - preventing the issue in the first place. For example, `EntityReference("contact", contactId)` can be rewritten as `EntityReference(Contact.EntityLogicalName, contactId)`.